# Handling lists as JSON reactjs

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to create a JSON dynamically through a array. Apparently my problem is that when I do `list.push`, they don't have a key.

`data` objects have a key, but `list` don't. How can I create the `data` variable from the `list`?

Thanks

[image: code screenshot]

[image: console.log outputs]

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding a list item to the list array, just add a key there.  Increment a counter in the loop and put that value into the list  E.g.

List.push({‘key’: count,
           ‘name’: ‘Place1’.....

Answer (score 0):

You want to know how can you create an object that matches `data` from JSON data? Try this:

```
// List should be an object with one key, "places"
let list = { places: [] };

...
// Instead of pushing to list, push to list.places
list.places.push( { name: ..., longitude: ..., latitude: ... });
...
```

Comment: tried that but got a different object.
`{places: Array(3)}` is the object I need to create
`{places: Array(0)}` after I did list.places.push

Comment: I need to create a `list` that I can handle as a JSON, like the `data` I have as an example

Comment: If `list` is still empty after you run the code, then that means your `database.ref(..).on(..)` isn't running? Are you sure that ref has data?

Comment: The problem was with firebase. I was running `this.setState(..)` code outside the `database.ref(..).on(..)`, so firebase didn't had the answer to the query before `this.setState(..)` was executed. 
Thanks for the help!